# How to prevent screen lock on Windows Phone

Tags: windows-phone, codenameone

I have a problem with screen lock on windows phone. I tried to use code below but it did't work:

```
Display.getInstance().setScreenSaverEnabled(false);
```

Is there any solution for my problem or Codename One simply doesn't support this feature on Windows Phone?

Thanks!

Comment: Is this a multi-media app?

Comment: App displays simple animation on screen. There are only images in used resources.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some codenameone features that are not supported on Windows phone.

Check if "Display.getInstance().isScreenSaverDisableSupported();" is returning true.

Comment: Thank you for quick reply. Unfortunately method returned false on my Windows Phone device.

Comment: Then unfortunately it's not yet supported on Windows phone. You can file an issue on https://github.com/codenameone/Codenameone/issues, it may take a while to get implemented though... as implementations are prioritised based on urgency, importancy, and how many pro and enterprise developers request for it.